# MySQL select all, having one column DISTINCT whilst also returning other corresponding columns

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(200)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| department  | varchar(40)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| type        | varchar(40)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(1000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| duration    | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| start_date  | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | N/A     |                |
| study_mode  | varchar(9)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| icon_url    | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to run a query that will output every department, eliminating the duplicates, as there can be two different courses that are part of the same department.

[image]

The query in the image essentially does what I want, the only problem being it outputs table 2 with only null values in each field as well. Is there a way I can run a similar query that only outputs t1?

Current Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `courses` AS t1 
LEFT JOIN `courses` AS t2 
ON t1.department = t2.department 
   AND t1.name < t2.name 
WHERE (t2.id IS NULL) AND (t1.type = 'Apprenticeship') 
ORDER BY t1.department\G
```

Comment: Don't use `*` if you want to control the columns in your query. In fact, don't use `*` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `SELECT *` use `SELECT t1.*`.

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM `courses` AS t1 
LEFT JOIN `courses` AS t2 
ON t1.department = t2.department 
   AND t1.name < t2.name 
WHERE (t2.id IS NULL) AND (t1.type = 'Apprenticeship') 
ORDER BY t1.department
```

Comment: Thank you so much!